# Text encryption in Console

Tags: java, encryption, console

How to immediately encrypt any text while typing in the Java Console?  I am talking about input and encryption happening concurrently(Just like how we type our passwords,which gets encrypted immediately,is that possible on console?). Or can anybody tell me which is the simple and the best way to encrypt the text while typing itself?

Comment: Does it need to be encryption, or can it just show random text?

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you actually mean the 'command line interface' (e.g. 'Command Prompt' on Windows 7) as opposed to the Java Console (which appears, if configured to do so, for applets and JWS applications)?  The user would not typically be typing in the Java Console, and if concerned about the security of the console, don't output any data to it!

Comment: Actually i meant the Java Console.And i'm using it on linux platform (though it doesn't make much of a difference)

Comment: What is the specific problem that you are trying to solve? Because the moment someone types a password a keylogger can record it. It does not matter if it is encrypted or not. More security can be achieved by using onscreen keyboard etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to encrypt an `OutputStream`, maybe you can use a [`CipherOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html). An example is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UsingCipherOutputStream.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Ok..Considering it is not possible to type a text and the encryption of the same text to go hand-in-hand IN-THE-CONSOLE, i learnt that this was the simplest way of encrypting and decrypting a text (of course,it needs external jar files) -

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor;

public class EncryptDecrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Password="password123";
        String text = "hello.I just encrypted this text and immediately decrypted it";

        //Encrypt
        BasicTextEncryptor btenc = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        btenc.setPassword(userPassword);
        String myEncryptedText = btenc.encrypt(text);
        System.out.println("Encrypted text:\n"+myEncryptedText);

        //Decrypt
        BasicTextEncryptor btdec = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        btdec.setPassword(userPassword);
        String plainText = btdec.decrypt(myEncryptedText);

        System.out.println("Decrypted text:\n"+plainText);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do let me know if there is a simpler way